# Spring-data-JPA : Join query best practices

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables T1 and T2.

[image]

I have to fetch the record from Table T1 where anotherColumn is null in T2 or not exists in T2.

Table T1 Entity relation with T2

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="t2")
private List<T2> t2s;
```

Table T2 Entity relation with T1

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="pId")
private T1 t1;
```

In the above scenario, it should return 2nd and 3rd records from Table T1.

```
@Query("select t1 from T1 t1 where NOT EXISTS (select t2 from T2 t2 where t1.id = t2.pId) OR EXISTS (select t2 from T2 t2 where t1.id = t2.pId OR t2.anotherColumn=null)")
public List<T2> findDisconnected();
```

Since I'm using inner subqueries it is taking more time.

```
Could please someone helps me,  
1) How can I optimize the above query? 
2) What is the best way to use join queries in Spring-data-jpa?
```

Comment: Your table structure is not clear. Is there any relationship between your 2 tables?

Comment: @GarimaGupta Yes,  Table T2 holds Table T1's id. ie., the second column in Table T2

Comment: So, T2 has ManyToOne relation with T1?

Comment: @GarimaGupta Yes, I have added those details. Please see the edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for

```
select * from T1 t1 full join T2 t2 on t1.id = t2.pId where t2.anotherColumn is NULL
```

here you are full joining two tables and fetching all the records which have a null value in another column.

Comment: Could you provide some description. I'm not able to figure out properly

Comment: added some description, check now.